# Import a R script (from current working directory) into Julia using @rimport

Tags: r, julia, rcall

I have a locally saved R program, layout.R , which is in my current directory (where I am initialising Julia). I was wondering if it possible to load this as a library using Julia's 'rimport' wrapper?

I know that for Python I have to run:

```
 unshift!(PyVector(pyimport("sys")["path"]), "")
```

to perform a similar action/operation. Is there an equivalent for the RCall library?